# Run method from class in new process

Tags: vb.net, process, runtime

I have an addin that is loaded into Autodesk Inventor when it's process starts. It adds some buttons etc.

Now I would like to use a functionality called `Apprentice` it basically is Inventor but lightweight. When you open and search files it is much faster than using Inventor because no graphics are loaded and only limited properties are exposed.

Sadly you can't use a `Dim m_AppreticeApplication As New ApprenticeServerComponent` from the Inventor process.

Is it possible to run a method that is called by pressing a button in Inventor to run in a new process? Without having to create a executable?

Something like CreateProcess(MethodToCall)?

Comment: I think this question would better fit in autodesk forums. [Here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-customization/implementing-apprentice-clientview-in-c/td-p/3460420) seems that you have an implementation in C#, converting it to vb.net should be trivial.Or [here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-customization/apprenticeservercomponent-replacereference-errors/td-p/5871842) in vb.net

Comment: I found these answers on the autodesk forums also but they are not ran from inside Inventor. I can create a test that works perfect from outside Inventor without a problem but when I run the same code from my ADDIN in the Inventor process, bad luck brian is there..